# How can I combine groupby and apply method for a loop function

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have dataset with three columns -"unique id”, “Period“, “flag1”. This dataset has around 800K+ rows with many unique ID's. I am generating a Flag2 as shown in result (for one ID only) . I would like to know:

1. how I can combine the below loop with groupby and apply method for each unique ID as shown in sample dataset.
2. As loop function on every row is very slow. Is there any alternative method to get the same result for each unique ID with better performance.

```
Sample dataset: 
ID  Period   Flag1
1   Jan-21  0
2   Jan-21  0
1   Feb-21  1
2   Feb-21  0
1   Mar-21  1
2   Mar-21  0
1   Apr-21  0
2   Apr-21  0
1   May-21  1
2   May-21  0
1   Jun-21  0
2   Jun-21  0
1   Jul-21  0
2   Jul-21  1
1   Aug-21  0
2   Aug-21  0
1   Sep-21  1
2   Sep-21  0
1   Oct-21  0
2   Oct-21  1
1   Nov-21  1
2   Nov-21  0
1   Dec-21  1
2   Dec-21  1
1   Jan-22  0
2   Jan-22  1
1   Feb-22  0
2   Feb-22  0
1   Mar-22  0
2   Mar-22  0
1   Apr-22  1
2   Apr-22  0
1   May-22  0
2   May-22  0
1   Jun-22  0
2   Jun-22  0
1   Jul-22  0
2   Jul-22  0
1   Aug-22  0
2   Aug-22  0
1   Sep-22  0
2   Sep-22  0
1   Oct-22  0
2   Oct-22  0
1   Nov-22  0
2   Nov-22  0
1   Dec-22  0
2   Dec-22  1
1   Jan-23  0
2   Feb-23  0
1   Mar-23  0
2   Apr-23  0
1   May-23  0
2   May-23  0
1   Jun-23  0

Result:
Id Period Flag1 Flag2(Out)
1 Jan-21   0     0
1 Feb-21   1     1
1 Mar-21   0     1
1 Apr-21   0     1
1 May-21   1     1
1 Jun-21   0     1
1 Jul-21   1     1
1 Aug-21   1     1
1 Sep-21   0     1
1 Oct-21   1     1
1 Nov-21   1     1
1 Dec-21   0     1
1 Jan-22   0     1
1 Feb-22   0     0
1 Mar-22   0     0
1 Apr-22   1     1
1 May-22   0     1
1 Jun-22   0     1
1 Jul-22   1     1
1 Aug-22   0     1
1 Sep-22   0     1
1 Oct-22   1     1
1 Nov-22   1     1
1 Dec-22   0     1
1 Jan-23   0     1
1 Feb-23   0     1
1 Mar-23   0     1
1 Apr-23   0     0
1 May-23   0     0
1 Jun-23   0     0
```

```
   df['Flag2'] = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(df):
        if df.loc[i, 'Flag1'] == 1:
            df.loc[i:i+11, 'Flag2'] = 1
            i += 11
        i += 1
```

```
I am trying to use groupby and apply method for the above loop but getting an error.
```

Comment: You cannot use something other than a loop here. Your condition is inherently iterative, you cannot vectorize it. One option to improve speed would be to parallelize of maybe use numba.

Comment: @mozway...while i have utlized for loop checking each ID and running the loop for Flag 2 and works fine for 2 to 3 unique ID's on a smaller dataset. Alternatively, how can i use groupby and apply method for each ID using above loop.

Comment: @mozway Thank you so much...yes! numba seems better options

Answer (score 0):

To use your approach with [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) create a custom function:

```
def flag(a):
    a = a.to_numpy() # more efficient
    out = np.zeros_like(a)
    i = 0
    while i < a.shape[0]:
        if a[i] == 1:
            out[i: i+12] = 1
            i += 12
        else:
            i += 1      
    return out

df['Flag2'] = df.groupby('Id')['Flag1'].transform(flag)
```

With numba:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def numba_flag(a):
    out = np.zeros_like(a)
    i = 0
    while i < a.shape[0]:
        if a[i] == 1:
            out[i: i+12] = 1
            i += 12
        else:
            i += 1
    return out

df['Flag2'] = df.groupby('Id')['Flag1'].transform(lambda x: numba_flag(x.to_numpy()))
```

Output:

```
    Id  Period  Flag1  Flag2(Out)  Flag2
0    1  Jan-21      0           0      0
1    1  Feb-21      1           1      1
2    1  Mar-21      0           1      1
3    1  Apr-21      0           1      1
4    1  May-21      1           1      1
5    1  Jun-21      0           1      1
6    1  Jul-21      1           1      1
7    1  Aug-21      1           1      1
8    1  Sep-21      0           1      1
9    1  Oct-21      1           1      1
10   1  Nov-21      1           1      1
11   1  Dec-21      0           1      1
12   1  Jan-22      0           1      1
13   1  Feb-22      0           0      0
14   1  Mar-22      0           0      0
15   1  Apr-22      1           1      1
16   1  May-22      0           1      1
17   1  Jun-22      0           1      1
18   1  Jul-22      1           1      1
19   1  Aug-22      0           1      1
20   1  Sep-22      0           1      1
21   1  Oct-22      1           1      1
22   1  Nov-22      1           1      1
23   1  Dec-22      0           1      1
24   1  Jan-23      0           1      1
25   1  Feb-23      0           1      1
26   1  Mar-23      0           1      1
27   1  Apr-23      0           0      0
28   1  May-23      0           0      0
29   1  Jun-23      0           0      0
```

##### timings

numba is faster for large datasets (>1000 rows), but only by ~40-50%. Tested here with ~10 groups.

absolute:

[image]

relative:

[image]